# JavaFX: HBox inside a StackPane not in the center

Tags: user-interface, javafx, pane, hbox

I used StackPane where all nodes are in the center. Now I want to have a node that is a HBox so that I can have horizontal elements in the center. For some reason, the HBox is at the top left even though its a node of StackPane.

```
HBox lines = new HBox();
lines.setSpacing(20);
lines.getChildren().addAll(firstLine, secondLine, thirdLine, fourthLine);
```

Here is the part with the HBox, and here where I add the HBox:

```
StackPane root = new StackPane();
root.getChildren().add(lines);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

The `HBox` is at the center of `StackPane`, more accurately it will fill all available space of StackPane. The items you see on top left are due to the HBox is aligning them like that way by default. Change this default value to

```
lines.setAlignment( Pos.CENTER );
```

Comment: I just found this out too, thanks. The problem I have now is that I still cannot position the nodes that are inside the HBox

Comment: This is a really old question but maybe this response will help someone else who comes along here. If you have a box (V or H box) that holds other boxes, you can position elements within their V/H box and then add that box to the parent box. For example, if you had a Text node in an HBox that was in a VBox, you could center the Text node in the HBox, then add the HBox to the VBox.